# AngularJS typeahead calling webapi

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

Using AngularJS with C# webapi here.

I am creating an input control, when the user starts typing in it I want to use typeahead and show the returned data.

I have setup the typeahead as below:

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" name="uName" ng-model="uName" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control input-medium" placeholder="Enter user name..."
   typeahead="uName for uName in getUserNames($viewValue)" />
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.getUserNames = function (search) {
        myService.getUserNamesFromApi(search).then(function (response) {
            $scope.foundNames = [];
            if (response.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    $scope.foundNames.push({ 'uName': response[i].uName });
                }
                return $scope.foundNames;
            }
        });
    };
```

The Data returned from my API is an array for example as:

```
0: {fName: "Adam", lName: "Smith", uName: "asmith123"},
1: {fName: "John", lName: "Bambi", uName: "jbambi456"}
```

And so on...

I am trying to get the uName part and push that to my array and then I return that array. But with this code currently it shows nothing, no error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to return a promise from your `getUserNames` function. That's how typeahead loads asynchronous collection, as soon as you type in something. And also return `$scope.foundNames;` from outside `if` condition.

```
$scope.getUserNames = function (search) {
    // return promise here.
    return myService.getUserNamesFromApi(search).then(function (response) {
        $scope.foundNames = [];
        if (response.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $scope.foundNames.push({ 'uName': response[i].uName });
            }
        }
        // return result from here.
        return $scope.foundNames;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks that was missing.

Comment: @user1563677 Glad it know it helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be as,

```
 typeahead="uName as uName.uName for uName in getUserNames($viewValue)" />
```